# Java 8 asynchronous non-blocking IO HTTP client

Tags: asynchronous, java-8, httpclient, nonblocking

I'm looking for any HTTP client library which makes asynchronous non-blocking IO for Java 8, i know that Java 11 has the new HTTP client which is able to do it, but i'm still using java 8. I have found the following http client so far: [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), so i would to know if [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) really does asynchronous non-blocking IO?

Comment: If your Java 8 VM is an Oracle or OpenJDK VM and you are ok with somewhat experimental stuff you could try out [http2client-java8](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/http2client-java8). This is a backport of the `jdk.incubator.http` HTTP client as published in JDK 10. It worked fine for my needs (HTTP2) but I don't believe it is still maintained.

Comment: @apophis I'm ok with it, but my team is not.  I will check it out on my free time and learning projects.